# Download PDF by URL giving 0 byte of corrupted file in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, clint

```
byte[] arrayofbyte = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("http://pdfurl");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrayofbyte);

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ContentType", "application/pdf; charset=utf-8");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".pdf" + ";");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
```

Comment: Only code questions are not welcome usually. How about adding some explanation about your problem?

Comment: You are downloading the file yourself, then forward it? Are you sure the pdfurl leads to a valid file, and that `ms` has content?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing the content length header.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", ms.Length.ToString());
```